# Has the operator $\frac{u \times v}{u^T v}$ a name?

Tags: cross-product

The operator $\frac{u \times v}{u^T v}$ gives a vector in the direction of the cross product, with magnitude equal to the tangent of the angle between $u$ and $v$. Does this thing have a name?

Comment: What does "the tangent of $u$ and $v$" mean?

Comment: The length of that vector is the tangens of the angle between $u$ and $v$.

Comment: @JohnHughes thanks for catching the typo, I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

$$\vec F=\frac{\vec u \times \vec v}{\vec u. \vec v}=\tan \theta ~~\hat n$$
Here $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec u$ and $\vec v$, $\hat n$ is a unit vector
along $\vec u \times \vec v.$ This vector doesn't seem to be given any name.

Comment: Now, that's what the OP already mentioned in his question ...  And as there are two unit vectors in question the answer doesn't seem really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it has no name.
to clarify to the commenters the norm of the vector,
 its length = $\tan(the \  angle \ between \ vector \ u \  and \ vector \ v)$ = $\tan{\left(\angle(u,v)\right)}$

$\| \frac{u \ \times \ v}{u^T \ v} \| = \tan(the \  angle \ between \ vector \ u \  and \ vector \ v) = \tan{\left(\angle(u,v)\right)}$